# LocalStorage для корзины товаров (React/Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, localstorage

Стоит задача, чтобы после перезагрузки данные корзины покупок оставались.
Я пытаюсь это прикрутить через LocalStoge и Redux.
Прошу помочь. Я совсем не понимаю иду ли я в правильном направлении.
В коде выделил все, что касается этой проблемы.

Мои попытки:

reducer

```
case 'SET_LOCAL_STORE': {
  const oldItems = {
    ...state.items,
  };

  return {
    ...state,
    items: oldItems,

  }
}
///////////////////////////////////////
default:
  return state;
```

action:

```
export const setLocalStorage = (itemsObj) => ({
type: 'MINUS_DELETE_ITEM',
payload: itemsObj,
```

})

Компонент Cart :

````
[JS]import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import cartEmptyImage from '../assets/img/empty-cart.png';
import { CartItem, Button, SubmitForm } from '../components';


import { clearCart, removeCartItem, plusCartItem, minusCartItem, minusDeleteCartItem, 
setLocalStorage}   from '../redux/actions/cart';

function Cart() {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { totalPrice, totalCount, items } = useSelector(({ cart }) => cart);

const addedDetectors = Object.keys(items).map((key) => {
return items[key].items[0];
});
 ```
/* В компоненте Cart пробую при загрузке записать данные в LocalStorage*/
React.useEffect(() => {
dispatch(setLocalStorage(window.localStorage.setItem('some-key', JSON.stringify(items)))); // items 
елементы корзины
}, []);
 ```

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 const onClearCart = () => {
 if (window.confirm('Вы действительно хотите очистить корзину?')) {
 dispatch(clearCart());
 }
};

 const onRemoveItem = (id) => {
 if (window.confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить?')) {
 dispatch(removeCartItem(id));
 }
 };
````

Полностью Reducer cart

```
const initialState = {
items: {},
totalPrice: '',
totalCount: '',
};

const getTotalPrice = (arr) => arr.reduce((sum, obj) => obj.price + sum, 0);

const _get = (obj, path) => {
const [firstKey, ...keys] = path.split('.');




 return keys.reduce((val, key) => {
    return val[key];
  }, obj[firstKey]);
};

const getTotalSum = (obj, path) => {
  return Object.values(obj).reduce((sum, obj) => {
    const value = _get(obj, path);
    return sum + value;
  }, 0);
};

const cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_DETECTOR_CART': {
      const currentDetectorItems = !state.items[action.payload.id]
        ? [action.payload]
        : [...state.items[action.payload.id].items, action.payload];

      const newItems = {
        ...state.items,
        [action.payload.id]: {
          items: currentDetectorItems,
          totalPrice: getTotalPrice(currentDetectorItems,),
        },
      };

      const totalCount = getTotalSum(newItems, 'items.length');
      const totalPrice = getTotalSum(newItems, 'totalPrice');

      return {
        ...state,
        items: newItems,
        totalCount,
        totalPrice,
      };
    }

    case 'REMOVE_CART_ITEM': {
      const newItems = {
        ...state.items,
      };
      const currentTotalPrice = newItems[action.payload].totalPrice;
      const currentTotalCount = newItems[action.payload].items.length;
      delete newItems[action.payload];
      return {
        ...state,
        items: newItems,
        totalPrice: state.totalPrice - currentTotalPrice,
        totalCount: state.totalCount - currentTotalCount,
      };
    }

    case 'PLUS_CART_ITEM': {
      const newObjItems = [
        ...state.items[action.payload].items,
        state.items[action.payload].items[0],
      ];
      const newItems = {
        ...state.items,
        [action.payload]: {
          items: newObjItems,
          totalPrice: getTotalPrice(newObjItems),
        },
      };

      const totalCount = getTotalSum(newItems, 'items.length');
      const totalPrice = getTotalSum(newItems, 'totalPrice');

      return {
        ...state,
        items: newItems,
        totalCount,
        totalPrice,
      };
    }

    case 'MINUS_CART_ITEM': {
      const oldItems = state.items[action.payload].items;
      const newObjItems = oldItems.length > 1 ? state.items[action.payload].items.slice(1) : oldItems;
      const newItems = {
        ...state.items,
        [action.payload]: {
          items: newObjItems,
          totalPrice: getTotalPrice(newObjItems),
        },
      };

      const totalCount = getTotalSum(newItems, 'items.length');
      const totalPrice = getTotalSum(newItems, 'totalPrice');

      return {
        ...state,
        items: newItems,
        totalCount,
        totalPrice,
      };
    }


    case 'CLEAR_CART':
      return { totalPrice: 0, totalCount: 0, items: {} };


///// Мои попытки ////////////////////
```

```
       case 'SET_LOCAL_STORE': {
         const oldItems = {
           ...state.items,
         };
   
         return {
           ...state,
           items: oldItems,
   
         }
       }
       ///////////////////////////////////////
       default:
         return state;
     }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашей ситуации лучше всего подключить redux persist. Настройка его займет мало времени.
Почему у вас action имеет такой тип:

```
type: 'MINUS_DELETE_ITEM',
```

Но его нет в редьюсере.
Работа с индексами плохая практика:

```
.items[0]
```

Почему при загрузке, а не при размонтировании пытаетесь записать. Вы ведь будете работать с корзиной и есть вероятность, что координально изменятся. Т.е. выходит, что записывать нужно не в этот момент;